# Spectrum of a Lax Pair and conservation laws of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, integrable-systems, lax-pair

If we have a Lax operator, we know that the spectrum of this operator is conserved over time.

Suppose that we have an equation that admits $L_u$ as a Lax operator, then can we say that all the conservation laws of this equation can be written in terms of the spectrum of $L_u$ ? Especially if $L_u$ has a discrete spectrum ?